# Extract one by one data from Database through Shell Script

Tags: database, shell

I have to code in Korn Shell. I have to take data from one database; and create "insert into" statements in a .sql file. And run this .sql file in another database.

There are 24 columns in the table; I'm not able to extract data from that table one by one in order to create insert into statement.

Can anyone help me with the same?

I wrote the following code till now(just a sample, with two columns data)

```
$ cat analysis.sh
#!/bin/ksh

function sqlQuery {

ied sqlplus -s / << 'EOF'

DEFINE DELIMITER='${TAB_SPACE}'

set heading OFF termout ON trimout ON feedback OFF
set pagesize 0

SELECT ID, H00
FROM SW_ABC
WHERE ID=361140;

EOF
}
eval x=(`sqlQuery`)
ID=${x[0]}
HOUR=${x[1]}

echo ID is $ID
echo HOUR is $HOUR
```

But here eval is not working.

Comment: Be aware, because you have quoted the heredoc terminator, the $TAB_SPACE variable will not get substituted.

Comment: You're probably approaching the problem from the wrong end. Instead of extracting the data with queries, does your database have a "bulk export" function?

Comment: I'm not very good with script extracting data. I had thought to take each column  separately and make an insert into statement for the columns. I'm probably not getting it right.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: We use Oracle database. Oracle 10.1g